# CentOS Unix Cron order of execution when all set to same time

Tags: linux, cron

I have a series of cron jobs running at the command line calling the php interpreter all by the same user configured to run once a day

```
0   0   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp.php
0   0   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp2.php
0   0   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp3.php
```

Do these all execute at once or do the execute in the order of entry in some cron table, complete and move on to the next cron job?

Comment: Belongs to **Super User** or **Unix & Linux**, not _stack overflow_  ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And to answer your question despite the off-topic:

They will get executed in parallel, not sequentially. If you need some order it would pay to add them all to one script, and execute them sequentially separated by &&, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp.php && /usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp2.php && /usr/bin/php -q /mydirectory/myphp3.php
```